# How to make the <af:column> of a table visible on click of a button?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Jdev version 11.1.1.7.1

I am new to ADF. I have a table in my UI. I have set the visible property to false to one of the columns of the table. Now how can make that column visible after clicking on a button?

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have table1 based on VO1.
VO1 has a column C1 that is conditionally visible in UI.

Solution:
a).You may create a transient attribute ShowC1Visible (Boolean) in your VO1.
b).You will create a custom method in your AM:

> public void showColumn(){
>            VO1RowImpl row = (VO1RowImpl)this.getVO1().getCurrentRow();
>            row.setShowC1Visible(true);
>         }

c). in your af:column, you will have a EL condition

```
<af:column  visible="#{row.bindings.ShowC1Visible.inputValue}"
```

d)  Drag and drop your custom method in your page to create a button like this:

```
<af:commandButton ... actionListener="#{bindings.showColumn.execute"} ...
```

e) in af:column tag, add a partialTrigger pointing toward your command button.